# Record Types Selection based on Profile or Prompt to Select?

Tags: record-type

I need to determine the best way to only show the specific `Page Layouts` associated with a `RecordType`.

I believe the recordtypes can be shown using Profiles, but am I correct in assuming that there could be a way to show recordtype-specific page layouts based on a subset criteria within Profiles? How do I do this?

1. I have two record types: Standard and Non-Standard
2. Within a Profile, some Users are needing to see Standard, but not all.

My solution would be to assign a new Profile for the group needing Non-Standard recordtype page layouts.

OR

Is it better to create an option for selecting record type if this group is assigned to the Non-Standard program?

Comment: You can use permission sets with access to record types, which can be assigned to users.

Answer (score 2):

The settings and permissions in permission sets are also found in profiles, but permission sets extend users’ functional access without changing their profiles. [help doc here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/perm_sets_record_types_assign.htm).

Steps to create permission set:

1. Create a permission set
2. Go to Object Settings
3. Click on your object name
4. You will be able to see all the record types listed. Assign the one you want to.

Assigning to a User

1. Go to user detail page
2. Scroll down to Permission set assignments and add the permission set created

Comment: Thanks. What are the advantages of this over assigning different page layouts to the Profile? I think it automatically prompts selection if there are two different page layout assignments within one Profile. I wasn't previously aware of this.

Comment: It prompts when there are record types in place and not because of multiple page layouts. Permission sets comes into play when users share same profile but need to have different level of access(like field editability, record access). So the basic level of access has to be given via profile, while any extra access or priviledge can be given using permission sets without changing the profile.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I fixed the issue by getting the record types  in order, but this permissions information is going to help me on a future project.